# declaring namespacesRequired array on page-level component

Tags: internationalization, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I've got a project based on next and react, using i18next package I encounter the following warning which I think is the reason why it takes plenty of time to load i18n according to react profiler:

> You have not declared a namespacesRequired array on your page-level
> component: withI18nextTranslation(Error). This will cause all
> namespaces to be sent down to the client, possibly negatively
> impacting the performance of your app. For more info, see:
> https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next#4-declaring-namespace-dependencies

notes : The translation works fine, I have declared namespacesRequierd in all of my components except 404.

this is my i18n config :

```
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default
const { localeSubpaths } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig
const path = require('path');

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
    preload: ['fa'],
    defaultLanguage: 'fa',
    otherLanguages: ['en','ar'],
    localeSubpaths,
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
    localeStructure: '{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
    fallbackLng: 'fa',
    ignoreRoutes:['/_next/', '/static/', '/public/', '/api/'],
    serverLanguageDetection: false,
    defaultNS: 'common',
    localeExtension: 'json'
});
```

next.config.js :

```
const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require('next-i18next/rewrites');

rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
           publicRuntimeConfig: {
               localeSubpaths
          }
```

versions :

package.json :

```
"i18next": "^19.7.0"
```

yarn :

```
    next-i18next@^6.0.2:
  version "6.0.2"
  dependencies:
    "@types/express" "^4.16.1"
    core-js "^3"
    hoist-non-react-statics "^3.2.0"
    i18next "^19.6.3"
    i18next-browser-languagedetector "^5.0.0"
    i18next-fs-backend "^1.0.7"
    i18next-http-backend "^1.0.17"
    i18next-http-middleware "^3.0.2"
    path-match "^1.2.4"
    prop-types "^15.6.2"
    react-i18next "^11.7.0"
    url "^0.11.0"
```

there's nothing related to this in my server.js file.

Comment: For those curious I've found this open issue on its github repository.
https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/384